# My switch(case) , keeps evaluating more than one case statement's

Tags: switch-statement, spinner

My problem is that my switch (case) statement keeps evaluating an extra switch case statement. And I don't understand why it's doing this.

My problem is in case 10: 
It's always being evaluated, doesnt matter what case # i choose. It will always run to case 10: and evaluate if it's true or not.

I'v been going over it and I don't understand what's going on. Why would it read case 10.

```
public boolean checkIfPossible(double x, double a, double y) {

    boolean pass;

    int value = spinnerA.getSelectedItemPosition();

    switch (value) {
         case 1:
             if (x > a && a == 0) {
                 etX.setError("Error1 "); 
                 pass = false;
                 break;
             } else if (x == a) {
                 etX.setError("Error2); 

                 pass = false;
                 break;
               }

        case 10:
            if (x == y) {
                etX.setError("Error3");
                pass = false;
                break;
            }

         default:
              pass = true;
    }

    return pass;
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, this is much better!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to put a `break` statement after your `if` and `else` statements in your **case 1** like this:

```
case 1:
        if (x > a && a == 0) {
            etX.setError("Error1 "); 
            pass = false;
          }

        else if (x == a) {
            etX.setError("Error2); 
            pass = false;
        }
        break;
```

The most likely reason you are having this problem is because the conditions for your `if` and `else-if` are both not satisfied. There is no `break` statement to stop the flow (since the `if` and `else-if` blocks are not executed). That's why your code eventually spills over to the next case. Try logging the value of *x* and *a* to verify.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!